# VBA MSXML2.DOMDocument60 LoadXML loads only up to 300 "entry" items

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to build a report based on data from MS Project Online/SharePoint database. I am using the approach described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2010/02/17/consuming-odata-with-office-vba-part-ii/) and it works perfectly until I encounter a table which has more than 300 records. When that happens I am getting exactly 300 "entry" items in my `objResultRF` collection. After some debugging it seems like if there are more than 300 records in the table, there are exactly 300 "entry" nodes in the `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` object after I am using its `.LoadXML` method. Could anyone please give me a hint where to look?

```vb
Function ODataReadUrl(ByVal strUrl As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim objXMLHTTP As Object
Dim objResultRU As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strUrl, False
objXMLHTTP.send
If objXMLHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
    Err.Raise ODataCannotReadUrlError, "ODataReadUrl", "Unable to get " & strUrl & " – status code: " & objXMLHTTP.Status
    Set ODataReadUrl = Nothing
Else
    Set objResultRU = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    objResultRU.LoadXML objXMLHTTP.responseText
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

    If objResultRU.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise ODataParseError, "ODataReadUrl", "Unable to load " & strUrl & " – " & objResultRU.parseError.reason
    End If
    Set ODataReadUrl = objResultRU
End If
End Function

Function ODataReadFeed(ByVal objFeed As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement) As Collection
    Dim objResultRF As Collection
    Dim objChildRF As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set objResultRF = New Collection

    Set objChildRF = objFeed.FirstChild
    While Not objChildRF Is Nothing
        If objChildRF.NodeType = NODE_ELEMENT And _
            objChildRF.NamespaceURI = AtomNamespace And _
            objChildRF.baseName = "entry" Then
            objResultRF.Add ODataReadEntry(objChildRF)
        End If
        Set objChildRF = objChildRF.NextSibling
    Wend

    Set ODataReadFeed = objResultRF
End Function

Private Function ODataReadEntry(ByVal objEntry As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim objResultRE As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim objChildRE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim baseName As String

    Set objResultRE = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set objChildRE = objEntry.FirstChild
    While Not objChildRE Is Nothing
        If objChildRE.NodeType = NODE_ELEMENT And _
            objChildRE.NamespaceURI = AtomNamespace Then
            baseName = objChildRE.baseName
            If baseName = "id" Or baseName = "title" Or baseName = "updated" Then
                Key = "odata_" & baseName
                Item = objChildRE.Text
                objResultRE.Add Key, Item
            ElseIf baseName = "content" Then
                ODataReadContent objChildRE, objResultRE
            End If
        End If
        Set objChildRE = objChildRE.NextSibling
    Wend

    Set ODataReadEntry = objResultRE
End Function

Private Sub ODataReadContent( _
        ByVal objContent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement, _
        ByVal objEntryDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim objChildRC As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objProperties As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objProperties = Nothing
    Set objChildRC = objContent.FirstChild
    While Not objChildRC Is Nothing
        If objChildRC.NodeType = NODE_ELEMENT And _
            objChildRC.NamespaceURI = ODataMetadataNamespace And _
            objChildRC.baseName = "properties" Then
            Set objProperties = objChildRC
        End If
        Set objChildRC = objChildRC.NextSibling
    Wend

    If Not objProperties Is Nothing Then
        Set objChildRC = objProperties.FirstChild
        While Not objChildRC Is Nothing
            If objChildRC.NodeType = NODE_ELEMENT And _
                objChildRC.NamespaceURI = ODataNamespace Then
                objEntryDictionary.Add objChildRC.baseName, objChildRC.Text
            End If
            Set objChildRC = objChildRC.NextSibling
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set `objResultRU.async = false` before `objResultRU.LoadXML`? Then again, you already have `objXMLHTTP.responseXML`, so no need to reparse.

Comment: OK, GSerg, that might work, thank you. objResultRU is of type MSXML2.DOMDocument60. objXMLHTTP.responseXML is DOMDocument. How do I typecast objXMLHTTP.responseXML to MSXML2.DOMDocument60 so I would be able to use its properties (DocumentElement in particular)? The property exists in objXMLHTTP, but it is empty for some reason...

Comment: The property exists in objXMLHTTP, but it is empty for some reason. At the same time objResultRU has a value in that property after its .LoadXML works out. Alternatively, if you could explain how do I use ODataReadFeed with objXMLHTTP.responseXML as an input, that would probably resolve my questions.

Comment: Use `= New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` instead of `= CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`.